# Multiple Eclipse IDE apps don't show up on Launchpad

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite

I need help with Eclipse IDE on Launchpad. I have the Mac OS X Yosemite and I've downloaded Eclipse IDE Java, PHP and C/C++. After I extracted and dragged and dropped the Eclipse IDE Java into my Applications, it shows up on Launchpad. But then when I extracted, dragged and dropped Eclipse IDE Java into my Applications, the app doesn't show up on Launchpad, and the same would be for the C/C++ as well. I have Java SE 6 installed, but reviews online doesn't help me

I would really like to have multiple Eclipse IDE apps on Launchpad but a second or third of these apps won't show up after a drag and drop into my Applications, can anyone help me here?

Comment: Are you sure the second drag is not just overwriting the first install? You probably need to rename the 'eclipse' folder to be something else for the second one. As the answer below says you can just use one Eclipse with all the components installed in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about this all wrong. Everything in Eclipse is essentially a plugin. You install one of the IDE versions - any one of the ones you want and then install the other plugins into that.

So in your case I would grab the Java IDE. Launch it. Then:

1. Go to **Help > Install New Software**. This will open up the Update site dialog.
2. Select **-- All Available Sites--** This will load all the update sites/categories
3. Select all the components you want. Based on your question you'll want to select the following:

   - Programming Languages > C/C++ Development Tools
   - Programming Languages > C/C++ Autotools Support
   - Programming Languages > JavaScript Development Tools
   - Programming Languages > PHP Development Tools (PDT)
   - Web, XML, Java EE, OSGi Enterprise Development > Eclipse Web Developer Tools
   - Web, XML, Java EE, OSGi Enterprise Development > Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
   - You may need some of the other Java things here like JSF*, m2e-* and what not if they were not already installed and if you plan on working with these Java features/frameworks so you can pick and choose anything else that looks necessary for you.
4. After you have select your items click next and continue through the installation wizard

Then you can just reopen Eclipse and you'll have all those features available. If you go to **Window > Open Perspective > Other** it will list all the perspectives avialable. A perspective is like a specific layout of panels in the IDE geared towards a specific task. And You can create you own perspectives as well.

Comment: ... and in the end you have giant heavyweight IDE which is super slow. Actually, it's a common thing to have multiple Eclipse installations – at least that's what I experienced. Of course there are ways to manage multiple Eclipse distributions within one installation (e.g. using -configuration on startup), but that's not what every user wants to deal with.