# Multiple Eclipse IDE icons don't show up on Launchpad

Tags: eclipse, osx-yosemite

I have multiple Eclipse IDE installed on Yosemite. I call them differently in the application folder, as EclipseKepler and EclipseMars. Only one shows up in Launchpad. Is there a way to show both?

Please note I am not interested in answers that would tell me to use a single Eclipse with multiple plugins. Apparently at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872740/multiple-eclipse-ide-apps-dont-show-up-on-launchpad) the user wanted such an answer but this is not what interests me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to rename the eclipse.app to eclipseKepler.app and eclipseMars.app don't forget to rename the eclipse.ini to have the same name as the app.

Comment: Actually, renaming the EclipseKepler.app/MacOS/eclipse file to something else (which breaks EclipseKepler.app) and back to its original name somehow solved my problem. Thanks for your help. If someone is confronted with the same problem, renaming the executable may solve the problem.